# Solr full refresh doesn't clear the index

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm having an issue where Solr won't clear the index during a full import.

All of the servers run Solr 3.4, the configuration is as vanilla as it can be.

I tried this on our development environment and on an instance on my own computer, and received similar results.

The schema is rather simple, these are the salient points:

```
<schema name="System" version="1.4">
...
  </types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0" />
    <fieldType name="documentKey" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer type="index"> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> 
      </analyzer> 
      <analyzer type="query"> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> 
      </analyzer> 
    </fieldType>
  </types>
  <fields>
    <field name="document_id" type="documentKey" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="entity_id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="entity_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
    <field name="Timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
  </fields>
</schema>
```

Of note:
 - The document_id field is calculated in the materialized view which is used to populate the index, and is a combination of other fields not in this index, but is indipendent of the entity_id. It's unique.
 - The entity_id field is the key of a couple of tables, and for the same document_id it can change wildly between a refresh and another.

Before a full refresh, if I query the index as such:

```
http://localhost:8080/qq-solr/system/select/?rows=10&q=document_id:%22French_Polynesia/Huahine~4034376%22
```

I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">5</int>
      <lst name="params">
        <str name="indent">true</str>
        <str name="q">document_id:"French_Polynesia/Huahine~4034376"</str>
        <str name="rows">10</str>
      </lst>
    </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
    <doc>
      <date name="Timestamp">2012-03-08T09:47:26.335Z</date>
      <str name="document_id">French_Polynesia/Huahine~4034376</str>
      <long name="entity_id">22902728</long>
      <str name="name">Huahine</str>
      <str name="type">LOCATION</str>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>
```

Then I refresh:

```
http://localhost:8080/qq-solr/system/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true&optimize=true
```

(I know the clean, commit, and optimize are redundant, but I used them just to make sure) and after a while I get the message that everything is a-ok.

Then I query the index again:

```
http://localhost:8080/qq-solr/system/select/?rows=10&q=document_id:%22French_Polynesia/Huahine~4034376%22
```

And I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">5</int>
      <lst name="params">
        <str name="indent">true</str>
        <str name="q">document_id:"French_Polynesia/Huahine~4034376"</str>
        <str name="rows">10</str>
      </lst>
    </lst>
  <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
    <doc>
      <date name="Timestamp">2012-03-09T08:31:07.317Z</date>
      <str name="document_id">French_Polynesia/Huahine~4034376</str>
      <long name="entity_id">22902728</long>
      <str name="name">Huahine</str>
      <str name="type">LOCATION</str>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>
```

But in the database the entity_id is different!

I see that the Timestamp has been updated, so that record has been touched, but why is the old value being retained?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but why are you using optimize with Solr 3.x? Have a look [here](http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/simon-says%3A-optimize-is-bad-for-you), you most likely don't need it, and it's even bad! I'd use optimize=false with dih to avoid that bad default behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run your DataImportHandler (DIH) process through the [Interactive Development Mode](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#interactive) so that you can assure that your database query is retrieving the entity_id that you are expecting. Because the timestamp on the solr entry is being updated, your DIH process is running, but I am guessing the cause for this lies in the way the data is being retrieved.

Comment: Did as you said, and the data seemed ok, but after that the core started working normally. What's odd is that this behavior lasted through several refresh and Tomcat restarts, and a different core in the same Solr instance wouldn't show the same behavior. I'll accept your answer as it's the one which has got me further ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Any time I'm doing an operation like this with Solr, I always manually clear the index first using curl to be 100% sure its wiped.  Here is a tutorial: http://www.alphadevx.com/a/365-Clearing-a-Solr-search-index